# Combining Forms auth and OpenIdConnect auth in the same WebForms app

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have a legacy multi tenancy WebForms app where users authenticate using forms authentication. We are migrating the auth system to IdentityServer4 but can't do it all at once, so we want to gradually introduce this to our tenants. This means we need to run the WebForms app with both Forms Auth and the new OpenIdConnect Auth at the same time.

My problem is that whenever I run `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge()`, I'm redirected to `Login.aspx` because of this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="AuthCookieName" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="60" protection="All" requireSSL="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

What I want is that whenever someone navigates to `/OIDC.aspx`, the challenge will redirect the user to IdentityServer as configured using OWIN. For all other requests, the existing Forms auth configuration can handle the authentication.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Were you able to make it working?

Comment: No, I never got this to work properly. What we basically did was to remove the entire OWIN pipeline from our WebForms ann. Then we  created a separate HttpHandler in our WebForms app where we handle the incoming JWT a bit more manually. Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: we were able to get something working by adding a location allow section in the web.config to the OKTA login page. 
on our webforms project we still register the startup class for OWIN and after the login challenge response we sign out of OWIN and automatically sign the user in with FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie.  this avoids confusion over multiple Identity contexts in our application.  SQLRoleManager stops working if you integrate OWIN with FormsAuth, but with this approach we are able to leave our application unaffected, and the user can still authenticate through OKTA.

Comment: @henningst can i ask did you need to use the Okta.Sdk library for the handler?  we built the above solution just using the Okta.Aspnet nuget library and it was able to handle the challenge and claims etc., without getting involved with tokens.   but we have run into an issue because of multi-tenancy where we need to check the issuer and then send a specific clientID & secret to match.  apparently we need to implement an Authorization code flow and it hasn't been easy to find how to do this with the SDK.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to prevent the unwanted redirect by setting the `Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` flag when invoking the authentication challenge, e.g.:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home.aspx" });
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge()` will do an authentication challenge against the default security scheme - in this case, yours is Forms Auth. You can pass in a string denoting what security scheme(s) to use in the challenge, like so `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)`

Comment: I'm getting the same result when running `.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)`. It seems like the forms auth is overriding everything. Is there any way I can keep these auth types separate even if they are running in the same app?

Answer (score 0):

OIDC uses Callback Url. This webform security restricts this url and redirects to login page. Allowing access to that call back url using location tag worked for me.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" name=".CLFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="authorization-code/callback">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```