# How to change authentication mode for a single Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, .NET version 4.8. I am trying to implement SSO using Azure AD and OIDC. The application currently uses `AuthenticationMode.Forms`, and the SSO implementation requires `AuthenticationMode.None`.

So, in the Web.config, commenting out the `Forms` mode and leaving `None` breaks the current username/password login implementation, and the SSO doesn't work the other way around:

```
<!--<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>-->

<authentication mode="None"></authentication>
```

Changing the Web.confing programatically in Controller actions works, *kinda*, but the Web.config is a shared resource, and I can't just change it whenever I like:

```
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (AuthenticationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
        section.Mode = AuthenticationMode.Forms;
        section.Forms.LoginUrl = "~/Account/Login";
        configuration.Save();
```

SSO and current authentication actions are in completely different controllers.

Is there a way to specify the authentication mode for a Controller or on a request basis?

Comment: You have to split the controllers into different web apps/projects. It makes no sense to mix forms authentication with SSO in the same project.

Comment: @dzenesiz Are you looking to support both types of authentication for the whole app? or just SSO for the whole app? or SSO for a particular controller? I know the question sounds unnecessary, given the title of your post, but there is a reason I ask.

Comment: @JuanR both types of auth for the whole app, but SSO is performed by a separate controller. The standard authentication is done from the SPA (Angular), which is the front end technology of choice. SSO is, on the other hand, initiated from an aspx View to avoid CORS issues Angular raises.

Comment: @dzenesiz I figured this was the case. Your question was not phrased properly. It made it sound like you only wanted SSO for a particular controller. Either way, I am glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it while staying in `Forms` mode. I just needed to suppress Forms authentication redirect before initiating the SSO process, like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;

        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult("OpenIdConnect", Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "AccountSSO"));
    }
```

I've found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54652479/2975357) SO answer.